# Reasons to move the WebSockets into a Worker Thread

Tags: javascript, html, websocket, dom-events, web-worker

I am running some tests with WebSockets.

For the test I used the Alchemy-Websockets .NET based server.

The web application open several windows and it used to monitor different services and systems.

I am especially interested in high load situation where the server has to sends a lot 
of events to the client, to reflect real time updates. I want the GUI to be fully responsive and present the data in a grid and a chart in a real time user experience.

I created the WebSocket in the main window thread, and on every incoming message I added an entry to an array that the grid is using to display (SlickGrid). To make the GUI work fine I added an setInterval of 20ms to render the grid updates, everything is working fine, very fast.

The question is whether moving the WebSocket to a worker thread is desirable or recommended. Reading about Worker threads I saw in the use cases a recommendation to handle I/O in a thread.

I think this make sense only if it is blocking.

As far as I know WebSocket is asynchronous and does not block. I read somewhere that 
it is implemented in a thread internally by the browser, which makes sense.

I consider moving the WebSocket into a worker, allowing the worker to buffer or aggregate some data before moving it to the main window, In case of high event rate I see the following approaches:

1. The main window thread polls the worker periodically (every 20ms or so) and get the required data.
2. The worker sends larger chunks of data periodically.
3. Every time the web socket receive data, send it to the main thread - but I think it introduce the same inherent problems. (This is where I began testing, I created an infinite loop in a worker thread
   and on every step I sent a message to the main thread, the GUI froze
   which makes sense).

Leaving the WebSocket on the main thread is also not ideal. In case of a high load from the server, the GUI will not prioritize the WebSocket incoming message events.

Gathering data in the worker thread, seems I might miss the real time updates during high loads, since the worker is buffering.

Another issue with worker threads seem to be the data duplication, which can be solved by the newer transferable objects, not sure how well it is supported on all browsers yet.

Why not hosting the WebSocket on the main window?

So what is the best practice?

Answer (score 1):

There are only two reasons to move WebSocket to Worker.

- JSON.parse is blocking operation and can cause FPS loss in case of big data. Data cloning from worker adds ~1% overhead, but 99% of parsing is done in background thread.
- Using SharedWorker to maintain only one connection with server.

Answer (score 0):

DOM manipulation and probably drawing on canvas affects websocket packages too. I measure around 0.2ms average latency on localhost, but using the same thread I have 4-9ms spikes in regular intervals. If I don't update the DOM that frequent or move the websocket to a worker they disappear. Chrome is affected the most, Firefox is better from this perspective currently. For online gaming this can mean some sort of lag or stuttering. For me it just affects TCP latency testing somewhat. I need to increase the message sending frequency from 1ms to 100ms to get a clean chart.